# Erro no loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

estou escrevendo um código e, no momento de percorrer a array, o vscode acusa erro na primeira linha do meu for, porém não consigo achar o erro, e não sei se é erro do vscode também.
Código abaixo:

```
const array = [[09, 13, 19, 24, 29, 46],[07, 15, 24, 41, 48, 50]];

     for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
    
      }
     }
```

No caso, o erro é acusado no "for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){"

conseguem enxergar algum erro?

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: expression expected.

Comment: O erro então não é pq não tem nada dentro do 2° for?

Comment: Já coloquei o argumento dentro do segundo for e o erro persiste. 
A palavra chave let, fica sublinhada nessa linha. Não sei se tem algo errado com a palavra chave.

Comment: Cara, coloquei no meu VSCode mas ele não mostra erro nenhum, coloquei pra rodar e funcionou

Comment: Então deve ser o meu vscode msm, vou ver se ele está atualizado, se não estiver vou reinstalar. Não tem outra alternativa. Vlw ;)

Comment: tenta reinstalar a extensão

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [[09, 13, 19, 24, 29, 46],[07, 15, 24, 41, 48, 50]]

 for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
    console.log(array[i][j])
  }
 }
```

Rodei no VsCode e funcionou normalmente. Se liga que o *let* e o *const* nasceram no ES5 ou 6, então dependendo do linter que estiveres usando ou da extensão no VsCode poderá haver a critica!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [[09, 13, 19, 24, 29, 46],[07, 15, 24, 41, 48, 50]]

 for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
    console.log(array[i][j])
  }
 }
```

Como pode ver, o programa roda perfeitamente. Deve ser algum erro no seu VSCode, tente atualizar sua extensão ou procurar alguma outra.

Eu recomendo a extensão Quokka.js. Ele serve tanto pra javascript quanto pra typescript. Ele executa seu código imediatamente enquanto você digita e exibe vários resultados de execução em seu editor de código.